# How To close ResultSet while implementing ResultSetExtractor explicitly

Tags: java, sql, spring, resultset, spring-jdbc

```
public class AddressRowMapper implements ResultSetExtractor<List<Address>> {

    @Override
    public List<Address> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
        

        while (rs.next()) {
                Address address = new Address();
                address.setCity(rs.getString("CITY") == null ? "" : rs.getString("CITY"));
                address.setState(rs.getString("STATE") == null ? "" : rs.getString("STATE"));
                address.setZip(rs.getString("ZIP") == null ? "" : rs.getString("ZIP"));
                
            addresses.add(address);
        }
        return addresses;
    }
```

Comment: Is it necessary to close the `ResultSet` from `ResultSetExtractor`?

Answer (score 1):

From: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html

> rs - the ResultSet to extract data from. **Implementations should not close this**: it will be closed by the calling JdbcTemplate.